# How do I get WPF DataGrid and AutoCompleteBox's Selected Item to play nice?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, autocompletebox

I've used the AutoCompleteBox without problem on a WPF form. Now I would like to do the same thing inside a WPF DataGrid. Almost everything works except the setter for SelectedItem. I see the getter get called but after typing a value and hitting tab (or using the arrow keys) the setter never gets called. In the console output I see no binding errors. I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get SelectedItem to fire the setter on the property in ViewModel class when it's inside a DataGrid.  First the snippet of the ViewModel class:

```
    public static List<ImpaSimple> AllImpas { get { return ImpaListRepository.ImpaList; } }
    private ImpaSimple _selectedImpa;

    public ImpaSimple SelectedImpa
    {
        get { return _selectedImpa; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _selectedImpa) return;
            _selectedImpa = value;
            //Manually set Description and Unit fields because user can override the IMPA default values.
           // Description = _selectedImpa.Name;
            //TODO Set Units too
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedImpa");
        }
    }
```

### The XAML

In the XAML below I have added a code behind handler for LostFocus as a temporary work-around. The addition of the UpdateSourceTrigger attribute was also an attempt to get this working.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource DataGridHeader}">LImpa</TextBlock>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Hots:AutoCompleteBoxEx ToolTip="Start typing an IMPA number"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding AllImpas}"
                                Width="50"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                FilterMode="StartsWith"
                                IsDropDownOpen="True"
                                IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                LostFocus="ImpaBoxExLostFocus"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImpa, 
                                                        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Hots:AutoCompleteBoxEx.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="450">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="275" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImpaId}"
                                   Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}"
                                   Grid.Column="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Hots:AutoCompleteBoxEx.ItemTemplate>
        </Hots:AutoCompleteBoxEx>

    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: In your grid's datasource - do you have any items with a preset SelectedImpa and if so does it display the value correctly? If it does the chances are there's smth. wring with AutoCompleteBoxEx SelectedItem implementation. It's typical for some controls not being able to server as editors. Do you own the source code for it?

Comment: I forgot I wasn't using the std AutoCompleteBox. AutoCompleteBoxEx is just a class I created via ` public class AutoCompleteBoxEx : AutoCompleteBox' so that I could hook the SelectionChanged event up to a handler that would scroll into view when the arrow keys are used. So yes I have the source but the functionality is coming from the wpf toolkit AutoCompleteBox. Next comment for other ansers.

Comment: **ALSO** I thought at one point during this journey I did have the auto complete box show up with data if a SelectedImpa had a non-null value but with the posted code that doesn't work either. I can see the getter being invoked but no value shows up in the auto complete text box. It acts link a bad binding value except I get no console output errors. I tried changing the context and that did generate binding errors. And the binding of ItemsSource to AllImpas appears to work as when I type I see the list of values, so that makes me think the data context is correct.

Comment: No value typically evidences that you binding didn't get picked up. With the derivaed classes it's quote often that designer don't think of inheritance scenario (and hosted scenrio too), so I'd check if SelectedValue of your sublcass gets changed in response to items selection through the grid.

Comment: I changed it to use the std AutoCompleteBox instead of my AutoCompleteBoxEx but there is no difference. There is no problem when the AutoCompleteBox or AutoCompleteBoxEx is **not** inside a DataGrid. I agree it looks like a binding issue but in the past with bad bindings I always get notified of such errors in the Output pane and I'm not getting any.

Comment: **PLUS** I can set a break-point on the SelectedImpa getter and it does get called and returns the correct value. But the value isn't shown in the ACB. The setter never gets invoked as a result of modifying the ACB.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I know what that is - the defect I call 'shy datacontext' - try setting your
Hots:AutoCompleteBoxEx DataContext to:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourDataSourceItemType}}}"
```

The way to check it is create a dummy converter and use it like that:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}}"
```

then put a breakpoint inside its Convert and check for the value. Since no Path is specified - the input value is the DataContext itself, if it's null, then it never gets set/got lost.

Comment: As written this wouldn't compile so I assume where you have *AncestorLevel* you meant *AncestorType*, but it didn't work. Each row of the grid is an instance of a view model class, in this case that class is OrderLineItemRowViewModel. So I replaced *YourDataSourceItemType* with vm:OrderLineItemRowViewModel. This generated a binding source error on DataContext. It seems like this should find the instance of the class that is on the row. The DataGrid's ItemsSource prop. is an ObservableCollection of this class, and the SelectedItem prop. is a single instance of this class.

Comment: sure it won't - jsut add it to your <Hots:AutoCompleteBoxEx DataContext="..." ...>

Comment: That is where I put it. but you did mean for me to use **AncestorType** not AncestorLevel,  correct?

Comment: Thinking about this, the binding is acting like it works but it's acting **Exactly** likes it is in **OneWay** mode. As a test I changed the Mode to OneWay and there was no difference. I get the feeling that even though I explicitly have Mode=TwoWay, something is overriding it.